# upper/lower_bound wrong comparison function parameter order

Tags: c++, stl, upperbound

[cpprefernce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) says:

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare > ForwardIt
> upper_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, compare comp );
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> `comp`    -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   requirements of Compare) which returns `​true` if the first argument is
>   less than the second.  The signature of the comparison function should
>   be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> (...) The type `Type1` must be such
>   that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type1`. The
>   type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be
>   dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type2`.

Having the following piece of code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct employee {
  string first;
  string last;
};

int main() {
  vector<employee> v = { {"John", "Smith"} };

  sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
       [](const employee& e1, const employee& e2) { return e1.last < e2.last; });

  auto p = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), "Smith",
                       [](const employee& e, const string& y) { return e.last < y; });
}
```

and the *Possible implementation* from cppreference:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt upper_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first,last);

    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (!comp(value, *it)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        } else count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

The parameters' order in lambda passed to `lower_bound`'s call should be reversed since `value` is a `const std::string&` and it's passed to `comp` as first parameter, yet it compiles like this and gives a compilation error if passed differently.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You show `upper_bound` doc, and use `lower_bound`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok my bad... I have just noticed that they `comp`s have different signatures in `upper_bound` and `lower_bound`